# What's the proper way to implement a custom SimpleCursorAdapter?

Tags: android, adapter, simplecursoradapter

I need the same functionality of a `SimpleCursorAdapter` but with a custom `bindView()` method. That's practically the only difference I would have in my custom adapter, and I want to have the rest of the functionallity of the `SimpleCursorAdapter` to stay as is.

Is it enough to just extend `CursorAdapter`? More specifically looking at the source of `SimpleCursorAdapter` one of the constructors is commented as:

> @**deprecated** This option is discouraged, as it results in Cursor
>   queries   being performed on the application's UI thread and thus can
>   cause poor   responsiveness or even Application Not Responding errors.

How do I make sure my custom adapter doesn't run on the activity thread? Do I need any of the other methods of the `SimpleCursorAdapter` such as `swapCursor()`?

Comment: had you heard about support library?

Comment: @Selvin yes, in fact the SimpleCursorAdapter I'm describing here is the one from android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;

Comment: the answer is Loaders API ... and yes, you need a swapCursor for this ... main problem with "old" CursorAdapter api was that it calls requey on UI thread ... with Loaders API you just swap the cursor which is queried on non-UI thread ... **edit:** also if *I need the same functionality of a SimpleCursorAdapter but with a custom bindView()* **why don't you use `SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder `**

Comment: @Selvin Thanks, the viewbinder was what I was looking for, you may want to post it as an answer.